# Sql Query to find whether the record entered is the first record or not on that day

Tags: sql, sql-server

Suppose we have a table with UserID ,Calendar date and taskName as columns.

Please let me know that from sql Query whether we can find that for a user id is it the first record entered in the table on that day or not.

Comment: is that work for you ???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> select case when ((select count(*) from table
>   where 
>         convert(Varchar,calendardate,111)=Convert(Varchar,GetDate(),111) 
>         and userid=(your userid))>0) then 1 else 0 end

Answer (score 1):

Make count of number of record in table

```
declare @count int
select @count=count(*) from table where 
      convert(Varchar,CalendarDate,111)=Convert(Varcar,GetDate(),111) 
      and UserID=@userid
if @count = 1
begin
   print 'first record'
end
```

if the count is > 1 than its not first record and if 1 than its first record

Answer (score 1):

```
      Select count(*)  from table where userid =:userid and date =current_date
```

If you want to check after inserting that record entered is first or not than run this after insert else prior to insert.

Answer (score 1):

If the table contains more than one record for a user in the same day you have to ignore the time part.

```
Select Count(*) From <TableName> Whre convert(Varchar,CalendarDate,111)=Convert(Varcar,GetDate(),111)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can make use of the windowed function [ROW_NUMBER()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186734.aspx) here.

```
SELECT  UserID, 
        CalendarDate, 
        TaskName,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY UserID, DATEADD(DAY, 0, DATEDIFF(DAY, 0, CalendarDate)) ORDER  BY CalendarDate, TaskName) AS RowNumber
FROM    T
```

Or if you have SQL-Server 2008 or later:

```
ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY UserID, CAST(CalendarDate AS DATE) ORDER  BY CalendarDate, TaskName) AS RowNumber
```

What this is doing is assigning each combination of UserID and CalendarDate (With the time portion removed) it's own incremental sequence in order of date (with time portion remaining, then the task name). `PARTITION BY` tells the `ROW_NUMBER` function when to start at 1 again (i.e. new date or new user ID), then the `ORDER BY` section tells `ROW_NUMBER` how to order the sequence. e.g.